# How can I Store backups of All My Servers on Another Server?

Tags: linux, rsync, backup, mysql

I have a new server that I'm planning to use for backup. On this server I want to store the `gziped` DBs from all my other 13 servers.
Which is the best way to make a backup every hour from each server and store it on the backup server?

Servers SO Linux Centos
All the 13 servers have WHM/Cpanel
The backup server have Centos 7.7 Only (No control panel)
I couldn't make the backups with cpanel because cpanel doesn't allow hourly backups.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `rsync` and `cron`.

On each server create file backup.sh with following line:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump > /etc/backups/mysqldump.sql
rsync /etc/backups/mysqldump.sql -e ssh <username>@<ip-address-of-backup-server>:/<path-to your-backup-folder>/<server-name>/"$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H")"-backup.sql
```

Check with [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) for dump options (or use your prefered method of dumping database). `<server-name>` should be some kind of identifier for the server the backup is from.

Put the file in `/etc/cron.hourly`. If you want different timing, you can check other `/etc/cron.*` folders or use [crontab generator](https://crontab.guru/) and use command `crontab -e`.

Make sure that `/etc/backups` (or your equivalent) exists or create it (`mkdir`).

Few common gotchas:

1. make sure to set up ssh keys at each server so `rsync` can connect to backup server and/or separate users with limited privileges. Depends on what kind of security are you looking for.
2. make sure that the `backup.sh` script is executable.
3. if you put `backup.sh` in `/etc/cron.*` folder it will be run with root priveleges. If you for whatever reason don't want this, use `crontab -e` option as desired user.